# Add XY points conditionally to raster map generated by levelplot

Tags: r, maps, levelplot

I have a tricky `ifelse` task here. Below is my code showing data for two periods(`future` and `current`). The data has `mean, 5th and 95th` confidence bounds alongside the xy cordinates. I want to compare the `mean, 5th and 95th` confidence bounds (CI) for the two dfs (`future` and `current`).

Conditions:

1) if the `CIs` for `future` do not overlap with those of `current` and CIs of futrue are above current, then`pch=2`.

2) if the `CIs` for `future` do not overlap with those of `current` and CIs of futrue are below current, then`pch=3`.

3) if CIs of future overlap with those of current, then `pch=4`

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

    s <- stack(replicate(2, raster(matrix(runif(100), 3))))
    current <- data.frame(coordinates(sampleRandom(s, 3, sp=TRUE)),
                     C5th=c(17.643981,16.83572,9.979904),
                     CMean=c(26.66364,19.74286,15.10000),C95th=c(35.68329,22.64999,20.22010))


    future <- data.frame(coordinates(sampleRandom(s, 3, sp=TRUE)),
                          C5th=c(17.643981,16.83572,9.979904)*2,
                          CMean=c(26.66364,19.74286,15.10000)*2,C95th=c(35.68329,22.64999,20.22010)*2)
```

The result of the above three `conditions` will then be added to my map.
Something like (just an attempt):

```
levelplot(s, margin=FALSE, at=seq(0, 1, 0.05)) + 
  layer(sp.points(xy, pch=ifelse(condition, 2, 3,4), cex=2, col=1), columns=1) +
  layer(sp.points(xy, pch=ifelse(condition, 2, 3,4), cex=2, col=1), columns=2)
```

For example, in the figure below, if the minimum of NFC (`future`) lies completely above the maximum of AFC (`current`), then condtion 1. if the maximum of NFC lies completely below the minimum of AFC, then condtion 1.The plot as shown below satisfies condition 3.

[image]

Please help.
AT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier if you define a complete `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object
with an additional categorical variable defined according to the
conditions you need.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

s <- stack(replicate(2, raster(matrix(runif(1000), 3))))
## Coordinates
cc <- sampleRandom(s, 3, sp = TRUE)
## Data
current <- data.frame(C5th=c(17.643981,16.83572,9.979904),
                      CMean=c(26.66364,19.74286,15.10000),
                      C95th=c(35.68329,22.64999,20.22010))

future <- data.frame(C5th=c(17.643981,16.83572,9.979904)*2,
                     CMean=c(26.66364,19.74286,15.10000)*2,
                     C95th=c(35.68329,22.64999,20.22010)*2)

cf <- data.frame(current, future)
## Define a categorical variable checking the conditions you need
cf$class <- with(cf,
                 ifelse(C5th > C95th.1, 'A',
                        ifelse(C95th < C5th.1, 'B',
                               ifelse(C5th < C95th.1 && C5th > C5th.1, 'C', 'D')
                               )
                        )
                 )
cf$class <- factor(cf$class)

## Build a SPDF object with the coordinates and data
pp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cc, cf)
```

This object can be displayed with `spplot`. With it you can choose the symbols, sizes, etc.

```
levelplot(s) + spplot(pp["class"],
                      pch = 21:23,
                      col.regions = 'gray')
```